# MySql relational query results

Tags: mysql

I have created this database. [image]

I am new to relational database. I am trying to run a query to display

```
Select candidates.CandidateName, candidates.CandidateVotes, candidates.Party, race.RaceName, mainrace.MainRaceName
From candidates  
JOIN ....
...
```

I've tried different options but I keep getting fields from candidates but nothing from other tables.

```
SELECT `candidates`.`CandidateName`, `mainrace`.`MainRaceName`, `race`.`RaceName`
FROM `race`
LEFT JOIN `electionpc`.`candidates`
ON `race`.`RaceID` = `candidates`.`RaceID`
```

Once I run this query I get `#1054 - Unknown column 'mainrace.MainRaceName' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join both tables:

```
SELECT candidates.CandidateName, mainrace.MainRaceName, race.RaceName
FROM candiates
JOIN race ON race.RaceID = candidates.RaceID
JOIN mainrace ON mainrace.MainID = candidates.MainID
```

Comment: I get the following error. SELECT candidates.CandidateName, mainrace.MainRaceName, race.RaceName
FROM candiates
JOIN race ON race.RaceID = candidates.RaceID
JOIN mainrace ON mainrace.MainID = candidates.MainID
 LIMIT 0, 25 

MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'electionpc.candiates' doesn't exist

Comment: There was a typo on candidates.

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you so much Quantastical. I really appreciated.